# What function do Xindi cheek holes serve?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, biology, xindi

All 5 of the extant sapient Xindi species have the same holes (and a line of bumps) on their cheeks, as can be seen below:

[image: Xindi-Arboreal male, a hairy humanoid with somewhat monkey- or lemur-like features and characteristic vertical slits on either cheek.]

[image: Degra, a male Xindi-Primate, the most human-looking of the Xindi species, distinguishable only by the same vertical slits on either cheek and strange hair styling.]

[image: Commander Dolim, a male Xindi-Reptilian -- his cheek holes are harder to see due to his heavily textured (scaly and creased) skin.]

[image: An unnamed Xindi-Insectoid with what appears to be two slits on beneath its eyes lateral to its mandibles.]

[image: Two Xindi-Aquatics seen in their aquatic environment through a window. A similar vertical slit and line of bumps are seen on their cheeks.]

Has it ever been explained what purpose they serve, or how such different species (which clearly diverged evolutionarily long ago) retain these cheek holes if they're purely cosmetic?

Comment: `retain these cheek holes if they're purely cosmetic` - Hey, what about our human anatomy: the appendix, wisdom teeth, and tail bone?  Two of those can easily be detrimental to our health

Comment: All vertebrate life on Earth has the same basic facial structure; two eyes, two nostrils, one mouth. We even have similar body structures; no vertebrate creature has its anus in the middle of its face, or six legs, for example. This has no real evolutionary advantage, but is simply the result of all Earth vertebrates being descended from an ancestor with a similar structure. There is no extant reason why the Xindi can't be descended from a creature with the same basic appearance. In fact, given the obvious genetic similarities needed for all five species to develop sapience, it seems likely.

Comment: @Izkata: Each of those features has served a non-cosmetic purpose. The appendix helps with digesting raw plant matter and could possibly still play a role in maintaining our gut flora. Similarly, the third molar was used for chewing foliage, and there's still controversy over preventative removal (ex. the NHS advises against it). The tailbone is necessary for several muscle attachments, so it's far from useless.

Comment: In any case, it's been 540 million years since the common ancestor between insects and humans, so that's a long time for even a vestigial organ to stick around, much less in 5 different evolutionary branches.

Comment: They are glands that secrete their pansexual pheromones. Haven't you noticed that everyone that comes near them starts moaning and putting their hands in their pants?

Comment: @James: I suspect there's a very good evolutionary reason why body plan symmetry is so common and why most animals don't have a digestive track that loops back to the head. Also, arthropods have evolved/re-evolved into many body plans, not just hexapodal ones. And, regardless, all arthropod body plans are highly functional. It's one thing for all arthropods to have six legs, or to have eyes and mouths on their heads, and an entirely different thing for them to all have non-functional holes in their faces.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: Who said they were non-functional? Presumably they hav *some* purpose, just one that we don't know of. Alternatively, there is no reason to presuppose that the various Xindi species separated from the same evolutionary branch as long ago as humans and insects on Earth. Again, given their cosmetic similarities and the fact that they all possess sapience, they likely evolved along the same path for much longer than humans and most other species on our planet. I also didn't say anything about symmetry, though it must be said that, while common, it is far from universal.

Comment: @James: Well, that's what I'm basically asking. If they did serve a function (at least at some point in the recent past--i.e. within 5 million years), their retention on all 5 races would be pretty reasonable. Since even our wisdom teeth are starting to disappear in some populations, despite their having been used as recently as 3 million years ago.

Comment: You're right of course. I don't believe their purpose has ever been stated, aside from the obvious 'so-they-look-alike' answer intimated by Richard below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-Universe, the common features shared by the 6 [Xindi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xindi) species; Xindi-Aquatics, Xindi-Arboreals, Xindi-Insectoids, Xindi-Primates, Xindi-Reptilians and Xindi-Avians are largely as a result of their **shared genetic heritage**. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xindi_%28Star_Trek%29#Xindi_history), they have over 99.5% of their DNA in common so it's hardly surprising that they'd have common physical features.

As you can see from the mask shots below, the ridges are sealed so there's little chance that they serve a physical purpose as glands or for breathing. It's more likely that the skin ridge is a function of supporting the bone ridge (and spines) below.

[image: Xindia Mask]

Out of universe, the decision to have the Xindis evolve from a common ancestor requires that they should look at least a *little bit alike* or fans would say "***if they evolved from a common ancestor, how come they look completely different?***"

Comment: Yea, seems like they were preempting a [_Reality Is Unrealistic_](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealityIsUnrealistic) audience response.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté At least they (sometimes) avoided the [Rubber Forehead Alien](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubberForeheadAliens "Title") trope by having the odd CGI character